# MS Access merge 3 queries in 1

Tags: sql, ms-access, pivot

I have the following table:

```
 tblFinances
 -------------------------------
   -FinancesID      => AutoNumber
   -FinancesDate    => Date
   -Price           => Currency
   -ReceiptYesNo    => Yes/No
```

and the following 3 queries:

```
qtrFinancesAll
    TRANSFORM IIf(Sum([price]) Is Null,0,Sum([price])) AS SumPrice
    SELECT Format([FinancesDate],"yyyy") AS [Year], IIf(Sum([SumPrice]) Is Null,0,Sum([SumPrice])) AS TotalPricePerYear
    FROM tblFinances
    GROUP BY Format([FinancesDate],"yyyy")
    ORDER BY Format([FinancesDate],"yyyy") DESC 
    PIVOT Month([FinancesDate]) In (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12);

qtrFinancesReceiptNo
    TRANSFORM IIf(Sum([price]) Is Null,0,Sum([price])) AS SumPrice
    SELECT Format([FinancesDate],"yyyy") AS [Year], IIf(Sum([SumPrice]) Is Null,0,Sum([SumPrice])) AS TotalPricePerYear
    FROM tblFinances
    WHERE (((tblFinances.ReceiptYesNo)="No"))
    GROUP BY Format([FinancesDate],"yyyy")
    ORDER BY Format([FinancesDate],"yyyy") DESC 
    PIVOT Month([FinancesDate]) In (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12);

qtrFinancesReceiptYes
    TRANSFORM IIf(Sum([price]) Is Null,0,Sum([price])) AS SumPrice
    SELECT Format([FinancesDate],"yyyy") AS [Year], IIf(Sum([SumPrice]) Is Null,0,Sum([SumPrice])) AS TotalPricePerYear
    FROM tblFinances
    WHERE (((tblFinances.ReceiptYesNo)="Yes"))
    GROUP BY Format([FinancesDate],"yyyy")
    ORDER BY Format([FinancesDate],"yyyy") DESC 
    PIVOT Month([FinancesDate]) In (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12);
```

Can I have one query instead of 3?

- qtrFinancesAll        => Show all Prices per Month.
- qtrFinancesReceiptNo  => Show Prices per Month where Receipt is No.
- qtrFinancesReceiptYes => Show Prices per Month where Receipt is Yes.

Thank you in advance.

UPDATED:

Desired output should look like this:

```
Year  Receipt  TotalPrice   1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10    11    12
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2018              1200     100   0   500  300   0   100   0    0    0   100   100     0
2018    Yes        800      0    0   400  100   0   100   0    0    0   100   100     0
2018    No         400     100   0   100  200   0    0    0    0    0     0    0      0
.
.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could select the data multiple times using a `UNION` query, and then pivot that:

```
TRANSFORM IIf(Sum([price]) Is Null,0,Sum([price])) AS SumPrice
SELECT Format([FinancesDate],"yyyy") AS [Year], Receipt, IIf(Sum([SumPrice]) Is Null,0,Sum([SumPrice])) AS TotalPricePerYear
FROM (
    SELECT [FinancesDate], Nz(SumPrice, 0) AS SumPrice, 'Both' As Receipt
    FROM tblFinances
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [FinancesDate], Nz(SumPrice, 0) AS SumPrice, ReceiptYesNo As Receipt
    FROM tblFinances
) As t
GROUP BY Format([FinancesDate],"yyyy"), Receipt
ORDER BY Format([FinancesDate],"yyyy")
PIVOT Month([FinancesDate]) In (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12);
```

An alternate, perhaps slightly faster but surely more weird way, would be to use a `CROSS JOIN` instead of a pivot to duplicate the data:

```
TRANSFORM IIf(Sum([price]) Is Null,0,Sum([price])) AS SumPrice
SELECT Format([FinancesDate],"yyyy") AS [Year], IIF(Bool, ReceiptYesNo, Null) As Receipt, IIf(Sum([SumPrice]) Is Null,0,Sum([SumPrice])) AS TotalPricePerYear
tblFinances, (SELECT DISTINCT Abs(ID Mod 2) * -1 As Bool FROM MSysObjects)
GROUP BY Format([FinancesDate],"yyyy"), IIF(Bool, ReceiptYesNo, Null)
ORDER BY Format([FinancesDate],"yyyy")
PIVOT Month([FinancesDate]) In (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12);
```

Updated:

Final code

```
TRANSFORM IIf(Sum([SumPrice]) Is Null,0,Sum([SumPrice])) AS TotalPrice
SELECT Format([FinancesDate],"yyyy") AS [Year], Receipt, IIf(Sum([SumPrice]) Is Null,0,Sum([SumPrice])) AS TotalPricePerYear
FROM (
    SELECT [FinancesDate], Nz(Price, 0) AS SumPrice, 'Both' As Receipt
    FROM tblFinances
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [FinancesDate], Nz(Price, 0) AS SumPrice, ReceiptYesNo As Receipt
    FROM tblFinances
) As t
GROUP BY Format([FinancesDate],"yyyy"), Receipt
ORDER BY Format([FinancesDate],"yyyy")
PIVOT Month([FinancesDate]) In (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12);
```

Comment: Thxs. I am getting an error in first "TRANSFORM". I added "UNION ALL" before that but still error. Maybe some () might needs and ORDER BY move in the end.

Comment: Try wrapping them in subqueries, as per the current edit

Comment: ... And? If you want me to help you further, you need to provide details

Comment: Tried the last code you edited and getting "Syntax error in FROM clause. (Error 3131)". Maybe more wrapping but where?

Comment: I testes both and getting errors. I think for me (better understand) is to use the first one. I am getting an error where "Nz(SumPrice, 0)" and change it to "Nz(Price, 0)". Now, I am getting an error in the first line, an input box ask me to write parameter for "price".

Comment: Please fix the queries in your question first. Further inspection shows you use `SumPrice` and `Price` both there, and apparently one of those doesn't exist. Provide adequate sample data...

Comment: Thanks it is working. Change the first line to this "TRANSFORM IIf(Sum([SumPrice]) Is Null,0,Sum([SumPrice])) AS TotalPrice". I will update your post to check the full code.

Comment: I added to the sql data from 3 tables. Is it a good idea? I was doing this in the past by merging 11 different queries!!! Now I can take the same result with 1...

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You could modify the Sum criteria for the two Yes-No fields:

```
IIf(Sum([SumPrice]) Is Null,0,Sum([SumPrice])) AS TotalAllPricePerYear,
IIf(Sum([SumPrice]) Is Null Or ReceiptYesNo="No",0,Sum([SumPrice])) AS TotalYesPricePerYear,
IIf(Sum([SumPrice]) Is Null Or ReceiptYesNo="Yes",0,Sum([SumPrice])) AS TotalNoPricePerYear
```

Comment: Since it's a `TRANSFORM` and `PIVOT`, only one column at a time can be transformed, and this won't work.

Comment: @Gustav Thank you for your reply. But it is not working.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth: Oh, missed that.

Comment: @YvetteLee: You must specify, what the desired output should look like.

Comment: @Gustav I have update my post with an output at the bottom.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Update my post. Thank you for your help.